# String's substring function vs StringBuffer's substring function

Tags: java, string, substring, stringbuffer

I went through the `String` and `StringBuffer` API and it seems both works same internally when you call the `substring` method.
Both have a ref to original char array (`char[] original`), so both are using same space.
Then why is `StringBuffer` prefered?
how is stringbuffer.substring(2,4) different then string.substring(2,4) then.

Substring method of StringBuffer:

```
public String substring(int start, int end) {
    return new String(value, start, end - start);  
}
```

Substring metohd of String:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
       : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

Both substring variants then call the String constructor:

```
public  String(char value[], int offset, int count) {
    this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count);
}
```

which calls below method of Arrays class:

```
public static char[] copyOfRange(char[] original, int from, int to) {
    // **char[] original**
   return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be a mistake to judge the value of `String` against `StringBuffer` on a single point. Yes they are very similar in functionality when taking substrings. No this does not contribute to the argument as to whether to use one or the other.

You should always use the best structure. `String` is immutable and should be used when immutability is required and in some edge cases. If you need to make changes to a `CharSequence` then it would be better/safer/faster/more memory efficient to use `StringBuilder`.

Consider removing a part of a string. Compare how you can do it using a `String` and using a `StringBuilder` - see how much easier it is. It isn't just easier, it is more efficient. The `String` mechanism creates two new objects and then adds them together to make a third. The `StringBuilder` one just removes the section of the string.

```
public void test() {
    String a = "0123456789";
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(a);
    System.out.println("a=" + a + " b=" + b);
    a = a.substring(0, 2) + a.substring(5);
    b.delete(2, 5);
    System.out.println("a=" + a + " b=" + b);
}
```

Comment: That's right but for only substring case-  String and Stringbuffer's  substring are exactly same ?

Comment: @Naruto_Uzumaki - They are allowed to be the same - but they are different in many other ways. Compare **removing** a substring from a `String` and from a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: yeah , exactly that's what i want to know.how is stringbuffer.substring(2,4) different  then string.substring(2,4)

Comment: @Naruto_Uzumaki - it's not significantly different - why should it be?

Comment: @ OldCurmudgeon - i meant memory space wise, both are same ? suppose original string (should say char value ) is 1 gb long , so even if i use stringbuffer.sustring(2,4) or string.Substring(2,4) then still both are  using 1 gb space as it still has reference to original array